# AS3 button to move movie clip in a mask

Tags: actionscript-3, button

I am new to AS3 scripting. I have a wide image (movie clip "preform_mc") that I am masking and would like for right button ("right_mc") to dynamically move the image.

The code below moves the image to the right, but its not a dynamic movement (would like an animation effect) and I cant control when the image should stop moving, basically a max amount for the x coordinate.

any help is greatly appreciated!

---

```
right_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    preform_mc.x += -100;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Greensock Tweening Library](http://greensock.com). Using that library you'll be able to easily make a smooth animation of a moving image. For the control of max X you should write an `if` statement to check whether preform_mc.x is more than the max amount you want.

Code will look something like this:

```
var min_x:int = -500;

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(min_x < preform_mc.x)
      TweenLite.to(preform_mc, 0.5, {x:preform_mc.x - 100}); // using the library I provided a link to
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped you. If you think that this answer was enough for your problem please mark it as correct.